# Hide UltragridRow that has no visible child rows after applying RowFilter

Tags: infragistics, dataview, rowfilter, ultrawingrid, dataviewmanager

So, I am setting the DataSource of my BindingSource to the DefaultViewManager of a DataSet that has a DataRelation.  I then set my BindingSource as the UltraGrid's DataSource before applying a RowFilter to the the "SalesOrderSublines" DataView.

```
public void RefreshData()
{
   var dataset = DataService.GetMillWorkOrders()
   bindingSource1.DataSource = dataset.DefaultViewManager;
   ultraGridSequences.SetDataBinding(bindingSource1, "", true, true);

   var dvm = bindingSource1.DataSource as DataViewManager;

   dvm.DataViewSettings["SalesOrderSublines"].RowFilter = "LINE_NO = 2;
}

public static DataSet GetMillWorkOrders()
{
   DataSet ds = OracleHelper.ExecuteDataset(_connectionString,        CommandType.StoredProcedure, SQL.GET_WORK_ORDERS);

   ds.Tables[0].TableName = "WorkOrders";
   ds.Tables[1].TableName = "SalesOrderSublines";
   var dr = new DataRelation("WorkOrderSublines", ds.Tables["WorkOrders"].Columns["WORK_ORDER"], ds.Tables["SalesOrderSublines"].Columns["WORK_ORDER"]);
   ds.Relations.Add(dr);

   return ds;
}
```

Then, as the UltraGridRows are initializing I want to hide any parent row ("WorkOrders") that has no visible child rows ("WorkOrderSublines") because of my RowFilter.

```
private void ultraGridSequences_InitializeRow(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Band.Key != "WorkOrders") return;

    e.Row.Hidden = e.Row.ChildBands["WorkOrderSublines"].Rows.VisibleRowCount == 0;
}
```

Although the RowFilter does work properly on the rows in the "WorkOrderSublines" band the VisibleRowCount of the band is still greater than zero and so the parent row is never hidden.  My guess is that I want to look for something other than the VisibleRowCount of the ChildBand to determine if the top-level row should be hidden, but I'm stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on `VisibleRowCount` you could simply compare the count of child row filtered vs total count.

```
void ultraGridSequences_InitializeRow(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Band.Key != "WorkOrders") return;
    var sublinesBand = e.Row.ChildBands["WorkOrderSublines"] 
    e.Row.Hidden = sublinesBand.Rows.Count(row => row.IsFilteredOut) ==
                    sublinesBand.Rows.Count();
}
```

Should be fine performance-wise so long as we're not talking huge amounts of records?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Filtering within the Grid may be an option rather than using the filtering in the DataSource.  The following resources have more details on implementing this:

http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/51892.aspx

http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=7703